# Share Dynamic Data on Facebook and Twitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharing, facebook-sharer

Is there some way to share some dynamic data from my page on facebook and twitter ?

I tried this code with static data and it worked, but I apply it dynamically it doesn't.

For Twitter:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" 
data-url="http://your.url.com/yourdynamicpage" 
class="twitter-share-button" 
data-text="What should I share?" 
data-count="horizontal">Tweet</a>
```

For Facebook:

```
<a href="javascript:window.location=%22http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=%22+encodeURIComponent(document.location)+%22&#38;t=%22+encodeURIComponent(document.title)" title="Share on Facebook..."><img src="/path/to/your/image/" width="12" height="12" alt="alt" /></a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you just want the URL that the links share to be the URL of the current page? Are these pages being created by a server-side language such as PHP, or by straight HTML?

Answer (score 1):

http://shantacreations.com/facebook_share_old/example_1/share.php/

yes the above link are functioning as you would like to make function.